# How do I clamp a 4ga armored cable ground to grounding rods?

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

I'm upgrading 100A service to 200A. The existing 6ga grounding conductors need to be replaced with 4ga. The existing 6ga armored cable was clamped to the grounding rods with these clamps (with the bottom flipped over...)
[image]

However, the spec sheet for these state they are only applicable for up to 6ga wire size. I'm not able to find a clamp for 4ga armored cable to a grounding rod.

I could use these: [image]

but then the armored cable would be pointing straight vertical. I want the cable laid horizontal.

Should I just go to a local supply store and ask them? Or is there a specific thing I should look for? Should I just use the existing clamp even though it says it's rated for 6ga and hope the inspector lets it slide?

Comment: An electrical supply would help you out. A box store would tell you #8 ground is fine, or other misadvice.

Comment: Are you *really* using “armored cable” as a ground wire? Seems unlikely.

Comment: In the time you took to write the comment, you could have googled "4/1 armored ground cable".

Comment: I'll leave this question "open" as my solution does not answer the question as written. It was an X-Y problem. I ran a #4 to the water pipe at the entrance, and then ran #6 to the grounding rods using the existing connections.

Comment: @000 So you didn't need 4ga? Or the water pipe is now the primary grounding electrode? There are some obscure rules about splices/connections on the grounding electrode conductor wire(s).

Comment: I think nobody was noting that "armored cable" and "bare armored ground cable" are quite different things. The similarity in names causes plenty of confusion. BTDT

Answer (score 2):

### Use a clamp designed for armored cable

I can't tell for sure, but I cannot see how the armor on your bare armored ground cable would terminate on the old clamp anyway, and you *need* to terminate that armor correctly at both ends lest you "choke" your grounding electrode conductor.

So, I'd use a clamp like the [Westgate MVP99-360-2C](https://westgatemfg.com/variation-detail/MVP99-360-2C) that is designed for clamping bare armored ground cables (the part in question is rated for #8-#4 wire, by the way), and thus provides a built-in terminating facility for the armor.  (I have no affiliation with them, and if you can find something else that works, more power to you.)